# Using multiple regression analysis to predict pricing

Tags: multiple-regression, stata

I am working for a company that bids on projects with a 30% markup. I want to run a multiple regression analysis on bid pricing. I was planning on using the following for my data:

**Dependent variable**:

Revenue - Revenue, in this case, is the bid price. It is the amount the firm offers to the vendor to do the project.

**Inependent Variables**:

Employee Costs - The amount spent on employees who were working on the project

Subcontractor Costs - The amount spent on subcontracting parts of the project

Production Costs - Costs for producing bids.

Payroll Taxes - Payroll taxes for labor costs

Overhead Costs - Extraneous costs such as Meals, Legal, and Autos expenses

I am using the program Stata to conduct my analysis and was planning on typing in the following input:

regress Revenue EmployeeCosts SubcontractorCosts ProductionCosts PayrollTaxes OverheadCosts

Is using multiple regression analysis, given the variables and data, a valid way to create a model that can be used to predict bid pricing?

Should I add a markup independent variable?

Should I use other data instead such as # of employees working on the project, # of hours spent on the project, rates of employees working on the project, etc.?

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Some tips for your question:

- Your question of interest above is not so clear. (so it is difficult to answer to "*Should I add a markup independent variable*")
- If several observations implies the same firm, panel analysis might be something you should look at: xtreg dependent_variable independen_variable time, vce(cluster id_company)
- Regarding "*Should I use other data instead such as # of employees working on the project, # of hours spent on the project, rates of employees working on the project, etc.?*", basically, this will be your work depending on what you think the best model is for your data/and question of interest... Choice of models can be according common sense, and, when it is not enough, maximisation of a criterion such as the RMSE (see comments below).
- Regarding "*Is using multiple regression analysis, given the variables and data, a valid way to create a model that can be used to predict bid pricing?*". I have no experience for that, but look at the $R^2$ of your model. If it is close to 1, it implies you are explaining most of the variation in the independent data. The method seems relatively reliable in those case. If it is far away from 1, there is a lot of things your model do not explain. You should not consider too seriously the prediction of your model.
  (However, you can still use your model to infer the mean impact of your variables on your bid. It can give you interesting insights)

Comment: When prediction is the goal, a metric like RMSE (or MAE, MSE, etc.) is usually a better option than $R^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. @user251625, see the below link (Google #1 result) for more details: https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/assessing-the-fit-of-regression-models/